# OCaml functions on uncertain data types

Tags: types, ocaml

I have a data type,

```
type data = IntData of int list | FloatData of float list
```

I want to write a function with signature `map : data -> ('a -> 'a) -> data` which will apply the given function to each element in the data's list.

The compiler doesn't like the following code, for understandable reasons.

```
let rec map dat func =
  match dat with 
  | IntData il = IntData (List.map func il)
  | FloatData fl = FloatData (List.map func fl)
```

Of course, the compiler can't make sense of the idea that `func` could have a different type in each of these cases.

On the other hand, I can't think of how to accomplish this kind of behavior, except to write a separate map function, one for `IntData` and another for `FloatData`.  But that seems like the kind of wasteful duplication of code that OCaml strives to avoid.

Comment: Minor note: your `map` function doesn't need `rec` as it's not recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *probably* want a data type that can represent either an int or a float.

```
type num = Int of i | Float of i
```

Where `data` is:

```
type data = num list
```

Now your `func` argument can be a function with type `num -> num` but not `num -> 'a` as you want a list of `num` as the outcome.

Of course, this means you cannot be assured your lists are only of ints or only floats.  It would be important to specify *why* you want to do this as there may be a better solution to the larger problem.

Comment: I see -- I may go with this solution.  I am structuring data this way to basically make a toy table data structure (lists of columns, each column a list of some data type).  I was hoping each list could be a single type, and I'm guessing this can be enforced if I seek a solution like the one you have here -- it just seemed like that might involve more complexity, and wanted to avoid it if I could.

Comment: Consider that lists are O(n) for random access. If you're doing something like this, you may wish to use _arrays_ instead.

Comment: Right, I thought about arrays, but then wondered how I would keep data consistent and so on.  Would it be an array of strings that all get parsed to an appropriate type when needed?  Would it hold ints that can map to other objects?  That also seemed complex, so I wasn't sure if I wanted to go down that route either.  I'll continue debating it, though -- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

While the previous answer is probably the simplest route, if you don't fear using [GADT](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html) which are admittedly a quite advanced feature of the language, and have the drawback of requiring more type annotation that standard variant types, you can define your `data` type as one:

```ml
type _ data = IntData: int list -> int data | FloatData: float list -> float data;;
```

then, it becomes possible to indeed indicate the relationship between the type of data contained in `data` and the type manipulated by `func`:

```
let rec map (type a) (dat: a data) (func: a -> a): a data =
    match dat with
    | IntData il -> IntData (List.map func il)
    | FloatData fl -> FloatData (List.map func fl);;
```

Note that you need the [locally abstract type](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html#s:locally-abstract) `(type a)` for the function to typecheck, since `a` will be instantiated differently in the two branches.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew the language had this feature! I'll probably play around with this too.

Answer (score 1):

Your map function first makes a decision on the type of list it's been handed, and then applies a function to that list.

The decision is whether to apply a function to a list of floats or to apply a function to a list of ints.

Presumably, the user will want a different function applied in those two cases! So reflect that in your code:

```ml
let map intfun floatfun = function
  | IntData intlist -> IntData (List.map intfun intlist)
  | FloatData floatlist -> FloatData (List.map floatfun floatlist)
```

Then the user can combine an int->int function with a float->float function, for instance:

```ml
let mapPlusThree = map (fun x -> x+3) (fun x -> x +. 3.0)
```

Comment: I think I see what you're doing.  But man, doesn't it feel off to have a single list of data and supply two functions, one of which won't get used?

Comment: @Addem Not to me - it seems like a very logical way to deal with your `data` type, which can have two subtypes, int or float, one of which won't get used. I don't know why you created this type and in what context you intend to use it, but that's how I would use it.

Comment: @Addem You could also alias `type datafunc = (int -> int) * (float -> float)` so that a "double-function" of type `datafunc` can be applied to something of type `data`

Comment: @Addem Also note, if you managed to write function `map` in a way that it takes only one function, how would the user use it? They wouldn't be able to pass it anything specific to ints and floats, since functions of int and functions of floats are different in ocaml. That's why I included the `+3 / +.3.0` example. How would a user do that with only one function? There is no function that can add 3 to both ints and floats in ocaml.

Comment: I mean, the ideal use case would be something like `map (IntData [1;2;3]) (fun x->x+1)`.  I think, from answers to this question, that this probably just couldn't be done though, for reasons that I think are along the lines of what you're saying here.  It sounds to me like I probably either (1) want to get serious and make this some kind of array, or (2) leave it in a toy state of design, and make each individual datum wrapped in an algebraic data type.  I can roughly see how each solution would go, each with pros and cons.